# Can I run bitcoind + lnd instances on my home-based computer to be publicly accessible?

Tags: server, self-hosted

Technically, I understand, I can start bitcoind and actually already running it on my home-based small server and lnd works with it quite well.

However, I wonder, how reliably this is in regards of speed for users around the world. Does it demand real high speeds or can I run it on my 260mbit/s down and 90mbit/s up connection with 43ms ping? The connection itself is stable.

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly you want to make publicly accessible?

Comment: @Murch I am building a webapp which makes transactions via Lightning network and uses LND + bitcoind to do so. So, basically, nothing would be accessible publicly besides some API endpoints of the webapp which would be used by the browser client.